# On click Submit form link including form parameter fields

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, forms

I have a plain html page on which I need to add a form that when you click "submit", it will redirect to another page `(page 2)` that will also include the form inputs.

For example:  `www.abcd.com/page2/?id=1234&sku=1&style=1` will be the destination page.

The form needs these fields:

1. Style = Drop down to select 2 styles with images
2. ProductID = Text field
3. ProductSKU = Text field

Comment: Kindly share code. What you have tried so far ?

Comment: use  `method="GET"` in your form tag

Comment: There is no need for JavaScript. Put page2 in the action, use method GET and add the fields with names id, sku and style

Comment: @mplungjan yes, thank you that is correct.. i was overthinking this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved as suggested by @mplungjan in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46150409/on-click-submit-form-link-including-form-parameter-fields#comment79262427_46150409):

> There is no need for JavaScript. Put page2 in the action, use method GET and add the fields with names id, sku and style

Answer (score -1):

You can use JQuery for this.

For example: when you are submitting you form you can redirect you page using using following method

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // cancel submission
  window.location.href = "https://www.abcd.com/page2/?id="+encodeURIComponent($("#id").val())+
  "&sku="+encodeURIComponent($("#sku").val())+
  "&style="+encodeURIComponent($("#style").val())
});
```

Comment: 1. No need for any JS, let alone jQuery. 2. You need to cancel the submit event or you will get conflicts. 3. You are not getting any values - you just send form.id.value as a string in your code until I fixed it. 4. Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help